# Jquery - Allow only 2 posts at the same time

Tags: jquery, post

Is it possible to say "Allow only 2 posts at the same time" in jquery?

Comment: If you could give more detail you will get better answers. Define what you mean by `posts` and `at the same time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean AJAX posts, yes there is. You would have to centralize all your POST requests into a queue or stack and error if the queue or stack is too big.